# More stats on stackexchange?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

On the right side of the main site there's a box:

[image]

However when clicking the "stack exchange" link, I don't get to a statistics page about Worldbuilding, but to the list of sites, which makes no sense to me (it certainly doesn't contain any statistics about this site). I remember that in the past this linked to one of the [User Reputation Leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/327/week/worldbuilding) for the site, which makes more sense; in any case, it should link to *some* site-specific statistics page, as that is what is promised by the link.

Comment: This is a more general issue; I'd advise posting about it on http://meta.stackexchange.com. As ArtOfCode mentions, it is not a bug but it doesn't seem to be great design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SE list of sites *does actually* contain some stats. When you click on a site's card, you'll be provided with some basic stats (some similar to the A51 stats, some different), and a link to visit the site.

That said, it certainly isn't clear. Not a bug, but neither is it good design.

Comment: It's definitely not a site-specific page. Just finding Worldbuilding there takes quite a bit of effort.